# How to override User-Agent in HTTP POST Request in Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps, user-agent

I've added a HTTP POST Request with Header "User-Agent" with a specified value, however the end system is not picking this up since LogicApps seems to override their own User-Agent. How can I force a User-Agent?